# How to display data in recyclerview depending on foreign key using Room library

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-room

After working with SQLite I came across Room library that greatly facilitates the work on my app, but I have a problem with sorting displayed data inside Recyclerview and I wonder how can I make my data list only visible with forgein key to a specific car.

**These are two tables that I'm working on:**

```
CREATE TABLE `cars` (`car_id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, `car_brand` TEXT, `car_model` TEXT, `engine_capacity` REAL NOT NULL, `horse_power` INTEGER NOT NULL, `inspection_date` TEXT, `insurance_date` TEXT, `year_made` INTEGER NOT NULL)

CREATE TABLE `fuels` (`fuel_id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, `fuel_type` TEXT, `fuel_amount` REAL NOT NULL, `fuel_cost` REAL NOT NULL, `mileage` INTEGER NOT NULL, `fuel_date` TEXT, `fueled_car_id` INTEGER NOT NULL, FOREIGN KEY(`fueled_car_id`) REFERENCES `cars`(`car_id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE )
```

Currently it looks something like this where I enter list I can see every item instead of one with a correct forgein key:

**Picture 1** - [list of cars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlNKA.jpg)
**Picure 2** - [list of refueling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozODz.jpg)

Car 1 - Refuel 1,2,3,4
Car 2 - Refuel 1,2,3,4
Car 3 - Refuel 1,2,3,4

and I want to accomplish something like this:

Car 1 - Refuel 1,3
Car 2 - Refuel 2
Car 3 - Refuel 4

**Fuel.java**

```
@Entity(tableName = "fuels", foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(entity = Car.class,
        parentColumns = "car_id",
        childColumns = "fueled_car_id",
        onDelete = CASCADE))
public class Fuel {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "fuel_id")
    private int fuelId;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "fuel_type")
    private String fuelType;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "fuel_amount")
    private float fuelAmount;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "fuel_cost")
    private float fuelCost;
    private int mileage;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "fuel_date")
    private String fuelDate;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "fueled_car_id", index = true)
    private int fueledCarId;

                 
    //constructor & getters/setters
```

**Car.java**

```
@Entity(tableName = "cars")
public class Car {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "car_id")
    private int carId;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "car_brand")
    private String carBrand;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "car_model")
    private String carModel;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "engine_capacity")
    private float engineCapacity;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "horse_power")
    private int horsePower;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "inspection_date")
    private String inspectionDate;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "insurance_date")
    private String insuranceDate;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "year_made")
    private int yearMade;

                     
    //constructor & getters/setters
```

**FuelDAO.java**

```
@Dao
public interface FuelDAO {

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM fuels")
    LiveData<List<Fuel>> getAllFuels();

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insertFuel(Fuel fuel);
    @Update
    void updateFuel(Fuel fuel);
    @Delete
    void deleteFuel(Fuel fuel);

}
```

**FuelRepository.java**

```
public class FuelRepository {

    private final FuelDAO fuelDAO;
    private final LiveData<List<Fuel>> allFuels;

    public FuelRepository(Application application) {
        CarList db = CarList.getDatabase(application);
        fuelDAO = db.fuelDAO();
        allFuels = fuelDAO.getAllFuels();
    }

    public LiveData<List<Fuel>> getAllFuels() {
        return allFuels;
    }

    //insert, update and delete methods
```

**ViewModel.java**

```
public class ViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private final CarRepository repositoryCar;
    private final FuelRepository repositoryFuel;
    private final LiveData<List<Car>> allCars;
    private final LiveData<List<Fuel>> allFuels;

    public ViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        repositoryCar = new CarRepository(application);
        repositoryFuel = new FuelRepository(application);
        allCars = repositoryCar.getAllCars();
        allFuels = repositoryFuel.getAllFuels();
    }

    //Car repository
    public LiveData<List<Car>> getAllCars() {
        return allCars;
    }

    //Fuel repository

    public LiveData<List<Fuel>> getAllFuels() {
        return allFuels;
    }
```

**FuelActivity.java**

```
public class FuelActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final int ADD_FUEL_REQUEST = 1;
    private ViewModel viewModel;
    private RecyclerView fuelRecycler;
    private RecyclerFuelAdapter RecyclerFuelAdapter;
    private LinearLayoutManager parentLayout;
    private Button goToAddFuelBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fuel);

        fuelRecycler = findViewById(R.id.fuelRecycler);
        goToAddFuelBtn = findViewById(R.id.goToAddServiceBtn);

        goToAddFuelBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, AddFuelActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, ADD_FUEL_REQUEST);
        });
        
        viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this, 
        ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory
        .getInstance(this.getApplication()))
        .get(ViewModel.class);
        viewModel.getAllFuels().observe(this, fuels -> RecyclerFuelAdapter.setFuels(fuels));

        createAdapter();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent dataFuel) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, dataFuel);

        Intent intentFuel = getIntent();
        int value = intentFuel.getIntExtra(String.valueOf(ProfileActivity.EXTRA_ID), 1);

        if (requestCode == ADD_FUEL_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String fuelType = dataFuel.getStringExtra(AddFuelActivity.EXTRA_FUEL_TYPE);
            float fuelAmount = dataFuel.getFloatExtra(AddFuelActivity.EXTRA_FUEL_AMOUNT, 1);
            float fuelCost = dataFuel.getFloatExtra(AddFuelActivity.EXTRA_FUEL_COST, 1);
            int mileage = dataFuel.getIntExtra(AddFuelActivity.EXTRA_MILEAGE, 1);
            String fuelDate = dataFuel.getStringExtra(AddFuelActivity.EXTRA_FUEL_DATE);

            Fuel fuel = new Fuel(fuelType, fuelAmount, fuelCost, mileage, fuelDate, value);

            ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel(getApplication());
            viewModel.insertFuel(fuel);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Refuel added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Refuel not added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void createAdapter() {
        RecyclerFuelAdapter = new RecyclerFuelAdapter();
        fuelRecycler.setAdapter(RecyclerFuelAdapter);
        parentLayout = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        fuelRecycler.setLayoutManager(parentLayout);
    }
```

**RecyclerFuelAdapter.java**

```
public class RecyclerFuelAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerFuelAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<Fuel> fuels = new ArrayList<>();

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerFuelAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_fuel, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerFuelAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Fuel currentFuel = fuels.get(position);
        String fuelAmount = currentFuel.getFuelAmount() + " L";
        String fuelCost = currentFuel.getFuelCost() + " PLN";

        holder.fuelTypeTv.setText(String.valueOf(currentFuel.getFuelType()));
        holder.fuelAmountTv.setText(fuelAmount);
        holder.fuelCostTv.setText(fuelCost);
        holder.mileageTv.setText(String.valueOf(currentFuel.getMileage()));
        holder.fuelDateTv.setText(String.valueOf(currentFuel.getFuelDate()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return fuels.size();
    }

    public void setFuels(List<Fuel> fuels) {
        this.fuels = fuels;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView fuelTypeTv, fuelAmountTv, fuelCostTv, mileageTv, fuelDateTv;

        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View view) {
            super(view);

            fuelTypeTv = view.findViewById(R.id.fuelTypeTv);
            fuelAmountTv = view.findViewById(R.id.fuelAmountTv);
            fuelCostTv = view.findViewById(R.id.fuelCostTv);
            mileageTv = view.findViewById(R.id.mileageTv);
            fuelDateTv = view.findViewById(R.id.serviceDateTv);
        }
    }
}
```

In DB Browser for SQLite I can see that data is added correctly and 'fueled_car_id' is the same as a 'car_id' that I enter from, but the problem is sorting it.

I've tried making a query in DAO class and making POJO class, but I couldn't fully understand syntax of it so it ended up not working and giving me errors like:

> Cannot figure out how to read this field from a cursor

or

> Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type

Thanks in advance for help